# Java NullPointerException even though object exists

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on a line where I call a method and pass it a string. I can only assume the string is null.

It was initialised from a `BufferedReader` readline a few lines before. Here's the relevant code:

```
FileInputStream tmp = null;
try {
    tmp = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("File not found!");
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(tmp);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));

create();

try {
    data = br.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("First readline failed: " + e);
    System.exit(1);
}
while (!data.equals(null)) {
    process(data);
    ...
```

and the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
       at enc.read(enc.java:40)
       at enc.main(enc.java:15)
```

Comment: So, which line is #40 and #15?

Comment: Where do you declare `data`? (I'm guessing that's your `null` `string`)

Comment: `null.method()` will trigger an NullPointerException for any instance method.

Comment: Please don't use a DataInputStream to read text. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your nullness check itself triggers the `NullPointerException`. Instead of `!data.equals(null)` write `data != null`.

Comment: bingo, that was it. Problem was the line number missing by a line and my lack of sleep.

Answer (score 6):

Without knowing the line numbers, I would suspect that the following is the culprit:

```
!data.equals(null)
```

If `data` is `null`, then a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Replace it with:

```
data != null
```

Comment: Now the big question... Who was first? :)

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, I think the bug is in:

```
while (!data.equals(null)) {
   process(data);
```

try changing it to:

```
while (data != null) {
    process(data);
}
```

You can't invoke a method from a null object.

Answer (score 1):

`while (!data.equals(null))` makes no sense. If `data` is `null` you cannot call `equals(..)`on it.

Replace

```
while (!data.equals(null))
```

by

```
while (data!=null)
```